How to verify signatures in pdf in ubuntu?
I would like to see signatures of a pdf file in Ubuntu. With Adobe in Windows is easy, but cannot find that option in Ubuntu. I am using evince.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. If my answer (below) works, please accept it by clicking on the checkmark in the left side

You can use Okular for that.
Install it with the command
sudo apt install okular

Now set Okular to be the default PDF viewer.
When you open a PDF with Okular, it will tell you that "This document is digitally signed".

Click on "Show Signatures Panel", and you can find the list of signatures.

Source:

https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/okular/okular//signatures.html
https://superuser.com/questions/1342994/how-to-verify-a-digital-signature-on-a-pdf-on-linux

Image source: https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/okular/okular//signatures.html
